# I am getting bitmap from SD card by path and set to ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am getting bitmap from SD card by  path and set to ImageView..  but ImageView is not shown bitmap on activity:

```
MainActivity.mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1); 
imageView1.setImageBitmap(MainActivity.mBitmap);
```

Comment: Code?? If any you have?

Comment: Great !! now we can clearly help you as you have put your question on SO... post some code.

Comment: Without seeing what code you currently have, we cannot help you.

Comment: Sorry i am new here. I have edited my question now.

Comment: Also remember that calling setImageBitmap() is a UI operation and must be performed on a UI Thread.

Comment: Did you make sure MainActivity.mBitmap is not null and it's a valid bitmap?

Comment: MainActivity.mBitmap is not null..

Answer (score 0):

why you are not setting the Image view using path

```
imageView1.setImageURI(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Finally i got solution ..
I was not scaling bitmap .